# Add lines not beginning with specific regex to previous line

Tags: sed, grep, tr

> sms;deliver;"+99999999999";"";"";"2012.06.23 09:21";"";"xxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxx,
>   xxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxx"

I need any lines that don't begin with "sms;deliver;" to be added to the previous line. i.e to get such a line :

> sms;deliver;"+99999999999";"";"";"2012.06.23 09:21";"";"xxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx"

^ That is a single line. Also it would be helpful to remove/replace any double quotes in the xxxxx(content) part.

sms;deliver;"+99999999999";"";"";"2012.06.23 09:21";"";"xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx "xxxx"xxxxxxxx"

So the above line would get converted to this(double quotes converted to single quotes):

sms;deliver;"+99999999999";"";"";"2012.06.23 09:21";"";"xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx 'xxxx'xxxxxxxx"

Comment: @nachito I have absolutely no idea how to shift lines to the previous one if the begin with some specific regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `sed` command seems to do what you need (edited: a short `sed` command in the beginning to filter quotes):

```
sed '/^sms;deliver;/!'"y/\"/'/" yourfile | sed -n '/^sms;deliver;/!b;:r;${p;b};N;/\nsms;deliver;/!{s/\n//;br};P;s/.*\n//;br'
```

A short explanation:

```
sed -n '# not print by default
/^sms;deliver;/!b # if line not starting with the pattern, goto end
:r #label r
${p;b} # if last line, print & exit
N # read new line, append to pattern space
/\nsms;deliver;/!{s/\n//;br} # if appended line doesn't start with pattern,
                             # remove newline & goto r
P # print everything up to the newline
s/.*\n//;br # remove what was just printed, goto r'
```

The `sed` in the beginning only changes `"` to `'` when it's not on a line with `sms;delivered;`

Comment: I need only the double quotes within the content part to be converted to single quotes. +1 for explanation

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;$!N;/\nsms;deliver;/!s/\n//;ta;:b;s/\(;".*\)"\([^";]*\)"\([^";]*"\)$/\1'\''\2'\''\3/;tb;P;D' file
```

EDIT:

Test data for `"`'s issue:

```
echo 'sms;deliver;"+99999999999";"";"";"2012.06.23 09:21";"";"xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx "xxxx"xxxxxxxx"' >/tmp/a
sed ':a;$!N;/\nsms;deliver;/!s/\n//;ta;:b;s/\(;".*\)"\([^";]*\)"\([^";]*"\)$/\1'\''\2'\''\3/;tb;P;D' /tmp/a
sms;deliver;"+99999999999";"";"";"2012.06.23 09:21";"";"xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx 'xxxx'xxxxxxxx"
sed 's/xx/"&"/g' /tmp/a >/tmp/b
sed ':a;$!N;/\nsms;deliver;/!s/\n//;ta;:b;s/\(;".*\)"\([^";]*\)"\([^";]*"\)$/\1'\''\2'\''\3/;tb;P;D' /tmp/b
sms;deliver;"+99999999999";"";"";"2012.06.23 09:21";"";"'xx''xx''xx''xx''xx''xx'x 'xx''xx''xx''xx', 'xx''xx''xx''xx''xx''xx' 'xx''xx''xx''xx''xx''xx' ''xx''xx'''xx''xx''xx''xx'"
```

Comment: @kedar see EDIT, although perhaps I didn't understand your requirement?

Comment: Issue is resolved,(the xx is just an example for any amount of text)